# Install scikit-learn on Mac

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation

I am new to the developer world. I tried to install Python and scikit-learn on my Mac for a new project. I installed the other packages (NumPy, pandas, etc.) which worked. However with scikit-learn I am getting an error. I used pip install sickt-learn and the installation start. For whatever reason I got the error message below. 
I am using Python version 3.8.0 (global) on a OSx machine 10.14.6. What did I wrong?
Thank you for your support!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JGKz.png)

Comment: Looks like your error message says it can't find the `Cython` module. Try installing that first

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. It worked. I installed Cython. However there was still an error. But following the installation guid posted in the error message. Solved the problem at the end. All packages are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run first:

```
pip install Cython
```